# PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager Vs ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder

Tags: azure, sharepoint-online, azure-ad-msal, adal

We want to authenticate our .net core console application against SharePoint online >> but seems there are 2 ways of doing so either using `PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager` or using `ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder` .. the 2 approaches are mentioned in these links:-

https://www.vrdmn.com/2020/06/using-net-standard-csom-and-msalnet-for.html

+

https://sharepointstew.wordpress.com/2021/07/07/app-only-authentication-in-sharepoint-online-using-latest-azure-sdk/

so which approach is most recent and recommended to follow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both the document are good are at their place. But when it comes to use would recommend using the second one because the second document has recently updated, and notes has provided there with performing in step by step and ideally the method of authenticate and getting access tokens is done using the Azure AD App Only and in the first one it is going with two step to access the share point i.e.

getting an application authentication (aka App-Only) access token using MSAL.NET and use it with the new .NET Standard CSOM to get data from SharePoint Online.

Another one more important thing in the second document they are using Generate Self signed Certificate and storing it to **KeyVault** but in the first document they are kept their certificate in local machine itself.